# bind TextView to Date

Tags: android, android-activity, data-binding, viewmodel, jodatime

I want to bind a TextView to a JodaTime date, so that if the value of the date is changed programmatically, the TextView will change with it. I succeeded in showing it the first time, but if the date changes the view doesn't get updated.

textview:

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/day"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{mainViewModel.day}" />
```

viewModel:

```
 public class RoomListViewModel extends Observable{
   private LocalDate day;


public String getDay(){
        return day.toString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    }

    public void previousDay() {
        day = day.plusDays(1);
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers();
    }

    public void nextDay() {
        day = day.minusDays(1);
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers();
    }
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable naming actually confuses you.

Since `TextView` works with `String` type, it calls your method `getDay()`. The `ObservableField<LocalDate> day` is not called in this case at all (from layout).

You need to use `@Bindanble` annotation to be able to change the layout dynamically.

Example:

```
private LocalDate mDay;

@Bindable
public String getDay(){
    return mDay.toString("dd/MM/yyyy");
}

public void previousDay() {
    mDay = mDay.plusDays(1);
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.day);  // you will have to import this (something like com.yourproject.BR)
}

public void nextDay() {
    mDay = mDay.minusDays(1);
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.day);
}
```

Your ViewModel needs to inherit from `BaseObservable` (if possible) or implements `Observable` interface (you can just copy the `BaseObservable` implementation).

[Haven't built it, may contain simple syntax error]

Comment: my ViewModel already extends java.util.Observable, I can't see how to do that with my configuration. If I implement databinding.Observable I guess I have to use addOnPropertyChangedCallback to listen to changes on the property, but how to do that?

Comment: Well, android data binding doesn't work with `java.util.Observable`. It works with `android.databinding.Observable`. Instead of extending this, extend from `BaseObservable` which already has needed implementation. Then just call the `notifyPropertyChanged(BR.day);`

Comment: yes I  know, unfortunately this app is built like that. I needed a quick fix for this particular case. 
thank you anyways, useful informations :)